# Two way relation between Pydantic models

Tags: python, pydantic

Let's say that a user has multiple posts and a post only has one user. I was wondering if there was a way to specify two-way relations (if it is at all desirable)? When the following is attempted, it results in "NameError: name 'Post' is not defined".

```
from typing import List
from pydantic import BaseModel

class User(BaseModel):
    id: int
    posts: List[Post]
    
class Post(BaseModel):
    id: int
    user: User
```

New to Pydantic, any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by means of [postponed annotations](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/postponed_annotations/):

```
from typing import List
from pydantic import BaseModel


class User(BaseModel):
    id: int
    posts: "List[Post]"


class Post(BaseModel):
    id: int
    user: User


User.update_forward_refs()
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach from [the same source](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/postponed_annotations/):

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import List
from pydantic import BaseModel

class User(BaseModel):
    id: int
    posts: List[Post]
    
class Post(BaseModel):
    id: int
    user: User

user = User(id=1, posts=[])
post = Post(id=1, user=user)
```

P.S. But it looks like wrong design. It is better to choose one direction.

Answer (score -1):

### What You're Most Likely Actually Looking For (2023)

So the way you wrote it, even if you get the annotations right, will eventually lead you to a Cyclic reference Validation Error.

If you're thinking more like a relational database's two way relation, assuming your model has an `id` field, you're wanting something like a Foreign Key.

In that case, just add a `<your_model_name>_id` field.

It can be a bit tedious, but it's better to have your model relations going in one way.

Example:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class User(BaseModel):
    id: int
    posts: List[Post]
    
class Post(BaseModel):
    id: int
    user_id: str  # <- or int, depending on how you want it setup. I'd recommend string though.

user = User(id=1, posts=[])
post = Post(id=1, user_id=1)
user.posts.append(post)
```

From my experience, this is the most proper way to handle this at the moment, and **I'm an avid fan of reverse relationships** haha.